# I want to refresh dom if new element (clone object) appended in inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to auto bind events of element(s) if i append element into `DOM` and the element is clone object. Here is code snippet:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Click Me" />​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        alert("Clicked");
        var cloneElem = $(this).clone();
        //cloneElem.bind("click");
        cloneElem.attr("value", "Click Me" + $("input").length.toString());
        $(this).parent().append(cloneElem);
    });
});​
```

Result:

[image]

If I click on `Click Me1` then it should also trigger a event which is similar to `Click Me`

Note:
I don't want to use `Live function` of JQuery to trigger event.

Answer (score 9):

[`.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) takes an argument whether or not to clone events as well:

```
$(this).clone(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function do_logic() {
        alert("Clicked");
        var cloneElem = $(this).clone();
        cloneElem.click(do_logic);
        cloneElem.attr("value", "Click Me" + $("input").length.toString());
        $(this).parent().append(cloneElem);
    }

    $(".clickme").click(do_logic);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want every handler to be cloned, this example should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        alert("Clicked");
        var cloneElem = $(this).clone();
        cloneElem.click(function(){
           // code to be executed when you click cloned element.
        })

        //cloneElem.bind("click");
        cloneElem.attr("value", "Click Me" + $("input").length.toString());
        $(this).parent().append(cloneElem);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add click event to cloned element also.

one way to do this ..

```
$(".clickme").click(AddClone());

function AddClone() {
    alert("Clicked");
    var cloneElem = $(this).clone().click(AddClone());
    //cloneElem.bind("click");
    cloneElem.attr("value", "Click Me" + $("input").length.toString());
    $(this).parent().append(cloneElem);
}
```